# Smarty - foreach stops while reaching a limit

Tags: html, smarty

i have a smarty foreach loop over a list of elements. this loop must stop when it complete 10 iteration, ie foreach must end at the 10th element of list.

```
{foreach $b_list as $list}
     <label>{$list['firstname']}</label>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{foreach $b_list as $list name=list10}
    {if $smarty.foreach.list10.index == 10}
        {break}
    {/if}
    <label>{$list['firstname']}</label>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{foreach $b_list as $list}
    <label>{$list['firstname']}</label>
    {if $list@iteration == 10}
        {break}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.